# Recover Nexus 6P that won't boot past Google logo

Tags: boot, nexus-6p

So I had a random reboot while debugging apps with android studio and after that device doesnt boot past Google logo. Factory reset and cache wipe do not help.

Eventually I found this guide https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6x7k-VkpUJRjl6WjRhVmdXU0E/view. But The problem is that I can't complete step 16 because device is enrolled in Adnroid beta program so there is no public image available that I need (NPG05F). I've found https://developer.android.com/preview/download-712.html but there is no Nexus 6P image listed for some reason. Will it be added soon?

Device OS is 7.1.2 (angler/NPG05F)

So is there anything I can do to get my device back?

Comment: Why do you have to follow that guide (taking OTAs versus just flashing a factory image)? Do you have any data to keep?

Comment: @AndyYan No, all data can go, it's fine. Problem is that flashing is locked so I can't flash anything except "Apply update from ADB"

Comment: To OP: bootloop with locked and non-unlockable bootloader is pretty much dead-end. I've looked around on XDA and it doesn't seem that sideloading a zip could solve it either, but doesn't hurt to try when the NPG05F OTA drops in the future. Shame that N6P doesn't have access to Qualcomm 9008 mode as a last resort as some phones do.

Comment: Gray area. Call google and complain about a hardware issue on the power button. It sticks and the phone is constantly boot-looping.  They did have issues with 5x and 6P so if you get someone who knows about those past issues, they may just send you a replacement.  Worth a try...

Answer (score 1):

ROMS for your device and instructions to flash them can be found here: https://developers.google.com/android/images

Hope this helps!

Comment: Device is locked, executing "fastboot flashing unlock" returns error. So I think I can only flash NPG05F images

Comment: What is the error it returns?

Comment: @ejj28 Newer devices require OEM Unlocking to be turned on in the OS before the device can be unlockable by that command in fastboot - I assume OP is bumping into this error. Since the OS is unbootable now you can't just go flip that switch either.

Comment: @AndyYan exactly. from all my unlocking attempts/successes on many new devices, recently, you need to boot into OS, make sure play services connects and your phone connects to your cell network before you unlock through terminal.  i root, unlock project fi phones, verizon phones for my job

Answer (score 1):

What I did when my Nexus 6P didn´t boot past Google logo and entered in a loop that never passed that state, was:

First, I entered in the Bootload section pressing at the same time the Power button + the volume-down button.

Then, pressing twice the volumen-down button I chose the Recovery-Mode option. (You confirm it by pressing the Power button)

After that, an Android icon with an exclamation sign logo will appear and below this a statement that says "no commands" or something like that.

Now, to enter the Recovery-Mode you have to press, not at the same time, but first the Power button and without releasing it press the VOLUME-UP button, and a screen with many options will appear.

I selected the "Wipe Data/Factory reset" option and when it finished, I turned the phone off.

Then I turned it on but it kept booting and rebooting never passing the Google logo, so I left it on my desk rebooting and went to my job. When I came back, after a few hours, the phone was perfect and had the screen they have when you for the first time turn it on and says something like "Welcome, choose language".

Summary, reset it to Factory and turn it off. After that turn it on and go for a walk or whatever but leave it rebooting a couple of hours. It worked for me and I hope it can work for other people too.

Greetings!